# How to add ssh key info @ Juju Charm for AWS

Tags: juju, aws

I am provision vms at AWS using Juju Charm.  How can I add my AWS ssh key to Juju so I can access to vms which I provision for MySQL, HAproxy and others.  thanks. 
Update...
I am provisioning vms at AWS using below commands so how can I add this ssh add command ( juju add-ssh-key "ssh-rsa .....) to environment or each vms?
This is commands I use for setup environment and provision vms.

```
juju quickstart -i
juju-1 bootstrap -e juju03
juju-1 deploy juju-gui
juju-1 expose juju-gui
juju-1 deploy wordpress
juju-1 deploy mysql
juju-1 add-relation wordpress mysql
juju-1 status
juju-1 expose wordpress
juju-1 status
```

Is there way to pull AWS security group while provision vms using Juju command? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `juju add-ssh-key <key>`

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/commands#add-ssh-key

See also:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/commands#list-ssh-keys
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/commands#remove-ssh-key

However, if you set up your ssh credentials when you bootstrapped with the same keys then Juju's already using those for authentication, then you can just ssh to whatever unit you'd like, like `juju ssh mysql/0` for example:

- [How to SSH into a Juju instance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152428/how-to-ssh-into-local-juju-instance)

Comment: Jorge.. thanks for that info.  I am running these Juju commands ( see below) so which status shall I run juju add-ssh-key "ssh-rsa ............ my commands....  juju quickstart -i
juju-1 bootstrap -e juju03
juju-1 deploy juju-gui
juju-1 expose juju-gui
juju-1 deploy wordpress
juju-1 deploy mysql
juju-1 add-relation wordpress mysql
juju-1 status
juju-1 expose wordpress
juju-1 status

Comment: Can you add that information to the question up above so it's easier to understand? thanks!

Comment: Jorge.. I just updated above.. pls take a look.  thanks.

Comment: @StevePe Have you tried `juju ssh wordpress/0` for example? your key should already be there for all the units.

Comment: I haven't so deploy all vms 1st then do that.. i will try it.. thanks again.

Comment: worked with IP address.

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# juju-1 ssh 54.173.7.60
Warning: Permanently added '54.152.229.59' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Warning: Permanently added '54.173.7.60' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/